# How to translate the messages from the micronaut-problem-json library?

Tags: java, micronaut

**What**: I would like to know how to translate the messages for the **micronaut-problem-json** library. Does it support `src/main/resources/i18n/messages.properties`? This information is not documented on the GitHub project's page.

The project: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-problem-json/

**Why**: The motivation for this is obvious, to support the internationalization of the messages.

This is a typical payload generated by the library in case of a constraint validation error:

```json
{
  "type": "https://zalando.github.io/problem/constraint-violation",
  "title": "Constraint Violation",
  "status": 400,
  "violations": [
    {
      "field": "create.signup.username",
      "message": "size must be between 3 and 30"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add support to other languages, like Portuguese, Spanish, etc. When an HTTP request from the client includes the HTTP header `Accept-Language: pt` the server should return the following payload:

```json
{
  "type": "https://zalando.github.io/problem/constraint-violation",
  "title": "Violação de integridade",
  "status": 400,
  "violations": [
    {
      "field": "create.signup.username",
      "message": "o tamanho deve ser entre 3 e 30"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, neither [micronaut-problem-json](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-problem-json) nor the [problem library](https://github.com/zalando/problem) uses Java Internationalization.

There are customizations that you can do within Micronaut. See [Micronaut Problem Json User Documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-problem-json/latest/guide/).

You can always request the feature or provide a pull-request.